# ODE involving matrix exponentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Exercise 5.14 (Hunter and Nachtergaele chapter 5). Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we define $f(t)=$ $\operatorname{det} e^{t A}$

(a) Show that
$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t)-1}{t}=\operatorname{tr} A
$$
where $\operatorname{tr} A$ is the trace of the matrix $A,$ that is the sum of its diagonal elements.

(b) Deduce that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, and is a solution of the ODE $\dot{f}=(\operatorname{tr} A) f$

(c) Show that
$$
\operatorname{det} e^{A}=e^{\operatorname{tr} A}
$$

I have used that $A$ is similar to its Jordan form. But not able to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$. Then $A$ and $J$, as well as $e^{tA}$ and $e^{tJ}$ are similar. So
$$
f(t)=\det e^{tA} = \det e^{tJ} = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{t\lambda_i},
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the $n$ eigenvalues of $A$. Now the three task should be very simple. Note that in (a) and (b) the matrix $A$ is fixed, and $t$ is the parameter to do differentiation. You do not have to take derivatives with respect to the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to solve the problem completely using this. This simplification was key. Really appreciate your help.